# The updated rgbdslam does not match with g2o?

Tags: slam, navigation, ros-fuerte

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Let me describe my questions in detail...

I am using fuerte, ubuntu 12.04. We have successfully installed the rgbdslam and openni and octomap in Dec 2012. I made a writeup to summery all the problems we encountered here at http://tianb03.blogspot.sg/2012/12/how-to-successfully-compile.html

Yesterday I have downloaded the latest version of rgbdslam and g2o. I have found that there are some more errors because of the path of the include files related to g2o. So I have searched the forum and found the questions in this link http://answers.ros.org/question/51013/rgbdslam-fixed-for-fuerte-where-do-i-send-the-patch/

This closed questions states a lot of updates for the rgbdslam. I have checked the version I downloaded in Dec 2012 and Jan 2013, the differences are just what has been mentioned in the question. However, I need to change the latest version back to the older version to make the package work.

More Details:
Change source file back to an older version according to the markers in the upper link.

in misc.cpp, need to include two more files from opencv. Or else gives some problems on the sift and surf algo..

```
#if CV_MAJOR_VERSION > 2 || CV_MINOR_VERSION >= 4
#include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"
#include "opencv2/features2d/features2d.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/nonfree/nonfree.hpp"

#endif
```

In CMakeLists.txt, remove the following two lines..

```
find_package(g2o REQUIRED)
find_package(libg2o REQUIRED)
```

By the way, I have successfully compiled the latest package. (I think I have changed it back to a previous version already). So I just want to know why it has been changed and is there a way to easily fetch the older working version? Or is there anyway no need to do so many revisions to make the latest version work?

Best regards,

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/53701/the-updated-rgbdslam-does-not-match-with-g2o?/) by [tianb03](https://answers.ros.org/users/1587/tianb03/) on ROS Answers with karma: 710 on 2013-01-30

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [georgebrindeiro](https://answers.ros.org/users/2573/georgebrindeiro/) on 2013-01-30**:
Please update your post with OS, ROS version, rgbdslam svn revision (`svnversion` when in the rgbdslam folder), error messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I can't reproduce your problems. It works fine for me.
Here is my setup, maybe that helps:

1. Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS
2. The current binary version of ros-fuerte-libg2o (2012.11.09-0precise-20121109-0201-+0000)
3. Rgbdslam from the repository http://alufr-ros-pkg.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/rgbdslam_freiburg at the revision 3856 (Which is for the whole alufr repository, rgbdslam was last changed at revision 3802, so everything after 3802 is fine)
4. Current versions of the libopencv-... binaries (due to an installation of openshot it seems, so maybe unrelated)
5. ros-fuerte-opencv2, ros-fuerte-vision-opencv
6. The current binaries for ros-fuerte-octomap, ros-fuerte-octomap-mapping, ros-fuerte-octomap-msgs, ros-fuerte-octomap-ros

I am not sure why it works for me and not for you.

I also do not understand what you mean by

> "However, I need to change the latest
> version back to the older version to
> make the package work. "

---

Originally posted by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) with karma: 6468 on 2013-02-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tianb03](https://answers.ros.org/users/1587/tianb03/) on 2013-02-04**:
Thx Felix. I will try to update all the packages you mentioned above. In my configuration, 12.04+Fuerte, not sure about the opencv version.  I need to change the files which are "Patched" in the mentioned link. And After that I compiled successfully..